# Как вывести пробелы из SQL запроса на страницу aspx?

Tags: sql, .net, asp.net

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Есть SQL запрос с таким выводом (при помощи пробелов):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня при выводе пробелы удаляются.

Как вывести также (с пробелами) в gridView?

Comment: пробовали &nbsp;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема в том что вы отображаете не строчку, а Html element.

Конечно вариантов масса.
1. добавить строчный блок.

2. `&nbsp;`
3. задать отдельный css стиль и экспериментируй с margin: 0 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0 0; 
   ....